# Kubernetes service not working as expected with kafka

Tags: network-programming, apache-kafka, kubernetes, apache-zookeeper, calico

I'm trying to setup a zookeeper and kafka as separate Kubernetes deployments/pods in a shared namespace. I've bootstraped a local K8s 1.8 with Calico via kubeadm on my Ubuntu sandbox...

For the Zookeeper, I'm using the image zookeeper:3.4 from hub.docker.com and I created a Kubernetes deployment and service, where I expose ports: 2181 2888 3888. Service name is zookeeper and I assume I should be able to use it by this hostname from the pods in the namespace.

For the Kafka 1.0, I've created my own container image, that I can control with environment variables... I'm setting the zookeeper.connect to zookeeper:2181.
I assume the Kubernetes DNS will resolve this and open the connection to the service.

Unfortunately I get:

```
[2018-01-03 15:48:26,292] INFO Waiting for keeper state SyncConnected (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2018-01-03 15:48:32,293] INFO Terminate ZkClient event thread. (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread)
[2018-01-03 15:48:46,286] INFO Opening socket connection to server zookeeper.sandbox.svc.cluster.local/10.107.41.148:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2018-01-03 15:48:46,299] INFO Socket connection established to zookeeper.sandbox.svc.cluster.local/10.107.41.148:2181, initiating session (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2018-01-03 15:48:46,319] INFO Session establishment complete on server zookeeper.sandbox.svc.cluster.local/10.107.41.148:2181, sessionid = 0x10000603c560001, negotiated timeout = 6000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2018-01-03 15:48:46,331] INFO Session: 0x10000603c560001 closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2018-01-03 15:48:46,333] FATAL Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.I0Itec.zkclient.exception.ZkTimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server 'zookeeper:2181' with timeout of 6000 ms
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.connect(ZkClient.java:1233)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:157)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient.<init>(ZkClient.java:131)
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.createZkClientAndConnection(ZkUtils.scala:115)
    at kafka.utils.ZkUtils$.withMetrics(ZkUtils.scala:92)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZk(KafkaServer.scala:346)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:194)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:38)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:92)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

So I was assuming I have a generic networking issue in my cluster, then I noticed something even more confusing for me... If I set zookeeper.connect to 10.107.41.148:2181 ( the current address of the zookeeper service ), the connection works ( at least from kafka to zookeeper ).

```
[2018-01-03 15:51:31,092] INFO Waiting for keeper state SyncConnected (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2018-01-03 15:51:31,094] INFO Opening socket connection to server 10.107.41.148/10.107.41.148:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2018-01-03 15:51:31,105] INFO Socket connection established to 10.107.41.148/10.107.41.148:2181, initiating session (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2018-01-03 15:51:31,134] INFO Session establishment complete on server 10.107.41.148/10.107.41.148:2181, sessionid = 0x10000603c560005, negotiated timeout = 6000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
```

With this setup I'm able to use the zookeeper service from the host of the kubernetes cluster to do for example "bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper 10.107.41.148:2181".
Producing a message does not work thou... I assume once the network is properly working, I need to add the kafka advertised adddress ...

```
kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 10.100.117.196:9092 --topic test1
>test-msg1
>[2018-01-03 17:05:35,689] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node 0 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Any hints what is wrong with my Kubernetes network setup or at least where to start troubleshooting?

Thank you and best regards,
Pavel

Answer (score 0):

If you use statefulsets, you need to deploy the service first.

Here my service.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zookeeper
  labels:
    app: zookeeper
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - port: 2181
    name: client
  - port: 2888
    name: server
  - port: 3888
    name: leader-election
  selector:
    app: zookeeper
```

Here the configmap (used later):

```
 apiVersion: v1
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
      name: zookeeper-cm
    data:
      jvm.heap: "1G"
      tick: "2000"
      init: "10"
      sync: "5"
      client.cnxns: "60"
      snap.retain: "3"
      purge.interval: "0"
```

Here my statefulset:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: zookeeper
spec:
  serviceName: zookeeper
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: zookeeper
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - labelSelector:
                matchExpressions:
                  - key: "app"
                    operator: In
                    values:
                    - zookeeper
              topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
      containers:
      - name: zookeeper
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        image: sorintdev/zookeeper:20171204m
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 500Mi
            cpu: 200m
        ports:
        - containerPort: 2181
          name: client
        - containerPort: 2888
          name: server
        - containerPort: 3888
          name: leader-election
        env:
        - name : ZK_REPLICAS
          value: "1"
        - name : ZK_HEAP_SIZE
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
                name: zookeeper-cm
                key: jvm.heap
        - name : ZK_TICK_TIME
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
                name: zookeeper-cm
                key: tick
        - name : ZK_INIT_LIMIT
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
                name: zookeeper-cm
                key: init
        - name : ZK_SYNC_LIMIT
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
                name: zookeeper-cm
                key: tick
        - name : ZK_MAX_CLIENT_CNXNS
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
                name: zookeeper-cm
                key: client.cnxns
        - name: ZK_SNAP_RETAIN_COUNT
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
                name: zookeeper-cm
                key: snap.retain
        - name: ZK_PURGE_INTERVAL
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
                name: zookeeper-cm
                key: purge.interval
        - name: ZK_CLIENT_PORT
          value: "2181"
        - name: ZK_SERVER_PORT
          value: "2888"
        - name: ZK_ELECTION_PORT
          value: "3888"
        command:
        - bash
        - -c
        - zkGenConfig.sh && zkServer.sh start-foreground
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - "zkOk.sh"
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - "zkOk.sh"
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /var/lib/zookeeper
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
        fsGroup: 1000
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
    spec:
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      storageClassName: zookeeper-class
```

After you deployed a working zookeeper configuration and they have elected a master, you can proceed with kafka deployment.

Once zookeeper is deployed, your kafka configuration must reference to zookeeper statefulset through the service. In kafka you must define/override this property:

```
--override zookeeper.connect=zookeeper-0.zookeeper:2181
```

From inside a pod you should `ping zookeeper-0.zookeeper` succesfully.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Nicola, thank you for your reply! I create the service before the Deployment / StatefulSet. The problem i face is that the dns settings on my cluster seem not to work... very strange...

Comment: @ppavlov : I added a note at the end of my answer. Bye